# Visual Studio 2019 Run as admin locks file

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, file-permissions, elevation

This is a bit of an odd one.

I am running Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise in a VM in Azure, and whenever I elevate to Admin any files that I build/save are locked by my user, i.e. I right-click on File Properties -> Security -> Advanced my user is the owner, but there is a shield icon next to it. This is causing me problems as when I run Visual Studio un-elevated I can't save the file until I have removed the shield icon by re-taking ownership. On other machines running Visual Studio 2019, I can do this without having to reset the permissions. Both machines have Windows 10 Pro with 1909 Build 18363.836 and both are set to be in Developer mode. The project accessed from the root of the C: drive.

Comment: This issue happens on all of your vs files?

Comment: Yes, it affects all the files that are saved/created